# Numerical eigenbasis for a unitary

Tags: matlab, diagonal

Do you know what numerical software computes an eigenvector basis for a
unitary matrix?

Say I have a unitary matrix $U$. If its eigenvalues are simple (no
multiplicities), then for instance Matlab computes an eigenbasis for $U$.
However, if there are some eigenvalues with multiplicities, in the subspace for the eigenvalues with multiplicity the software does not find independent eigenvectors. If a matrix is symmetric or Hermitian, Matlab is
programmed to output an eigenbasis (even if there are eigenvalues with
multiplicities). No such thing for unitary matrices - as fas as I know.

I found a way to avoid this: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity,
then I can form the matrix $B=A-\lambda\cdot\mathbf{1}$ and find the nullity
of $B$. The only problem is that doing this for each possible eigenvalue is
slow. I wonder if there is a better solution.

If that makes a difference, I can assume that my unitary matrix is real.

The question was also asked here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/numerical-eigenbasis-for-a-unitary